# Hadoop distcp with partition

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am trying to do distcp from one system to other with same configurations(say A to B). But the partitions that i created in A are not showing up in B after distcp from A to B. I have to manually create the partitions in B.

I have gone through set dynamic partition parameter but it just adds partitions which is a different thing. 
Please let me know is there anyway to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair table on System B (where your data is copied) after distcp, execute following hive commands

```
SET hive.mapred.mode=unstrict;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE <DB_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
```